# Enable/disable checkboxs using links instead of checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a checkbox to add and remove a service. Currently it looks like this:

```
<div class="cknow" align="center" valign="top">Add/Remove to Checkout
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckNow_<?php echo $i;?>" name="ckNow[<?php echo $i;?>]"></input>
</div>
```

I've also got a script that says this:

```
$('input[id^=ckNow_]').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click',function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked'))
        {.... does some stuff }
```

It's working great as a single checkbox but I'd like to the make the text 'Add/Remove' to be text links (without the input box of the checkbox) so that when Add is clicked it registers as CHECKED and when Remove is clicked, it registers as UNCHECKED.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `label` element to assign text to a checkbox, then use CSS to hide the checkbox like so:

HTML

```
<label>Add/Remove
  <input type="checkbox" id="ckNow_" name="ckNow" class="hideme">
  </input>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.hideme {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I want Add to be one text link and Remove to be another, both tied to the same checkbox... so if Add is clicked, the checkbox is considered checked and if remove is clicked, the checkbox is considered unchecked.

Comment: this is a good native solution but it not as adjustable as a JS solution.

Comment: @user1172854 Then you might want to reconsider your setup here. Instead of using checkboxes, just use anchor elements and do stuff based on which one you clicked.

Comment: Thank you. +'d for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true); // or false
```

Note: of jQuery 1.7 you should use `.prop('checked', ...)` instead:

```
$('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true); // or false
```